# Why can't LexV2 understand which intent to switch to when prompted with the exact utterance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I'm new to LexV2. Built bots and tested them on the LexConsole. Works nicely.
Since then, I've installed AWSSDK for Dotnet (c#)
And, that's where the confusion started.

```
var session_id = AwsBotDeployTest.Glob.RandomSessionId;
var session_state = new SessionState()
{
    Intent = new Intent()
    {
        Name = "WelcomeIntent",
        ConfirmationState = "None",
        State = "Fulfilled"
    },
    DialogAction = new DialogAction()
    {
        Type = "Delegate"
    }
};
var request = new Amazon.LexRuntimeV2.Model.PutSessionRequest()
{
    BotId = "MYBOTID",
    BotAliasId = "MYBOTALIASID",
    LocaleId = "en_GB",
    ResponseContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    SessionId = session_id,
    SessionStateValue = session_state,
    Messages = new List<Message>()
};
var response = await client.PutSessionAsync(request);
```

As you can see above, I'm first sending no messages and my 'WelcomeIntent' is configured to go straight to the closing message. Here's the configuration for the 'WelcomeIntent':

[image: WelcomeIntent Config]

After this part of the code, I have a loop that allows me to type responses to the bot using the console:

```
while (true)
{
    session_state = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionState>(AwsBotDeployTest.Glob.Decompress(response.SessionStateValue));
    bot_messages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Message>>(AwsBotDeployTest.Glob.Decompress(response.Messages));
    if (bot_messages != null)
    {
        foreach (Message message in bot_messages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Bot: {message.Content}");
        }
    }
    request.SessionStateValue = session_state;
    request.Messages.Clear();
    prompt = Console.ReadLine();
    request.Messages.Add(new Message()
    {
        ContentType = "PlainText",
        Content = prompt
    });
    response = await client.PutSessionAsync(request);
}
```

From this section, you can hopefully see, that I'm just replacing the session state in the request object with the one in the response and then just printing out the bot's messages.
Here's another intent I have set up for tracking orders, showing the utterances.

[image: TrackOrder Utterances]

Yet, when I prompt the bot with these utterances, the bot simply repeats the message from the WelcomeIntent.

[image: Bot Console Chat]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like I should only have been using PutSession when initializing the conversation. After initialization, it looks like I'm suppose to use "RecognizeText" to make further requests.

I'm still running into problems, for which the documentation is lacking an explanation, but I'll just open another question.